# Php Login works but ignoring user type field in MySQL script

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, authentication

Was hoping I could get a bit of a hand on this login that I have been stuck with for past few days.

Basically what it is is that the login will log in the user, but will go to the same page every time. What I want it to do is: If the user is an admin, take that person to the admin page. If user, to the userpage.

I've set it up in the database were there is a usertype field and have hard coded 2 users, with one have admin as their usertype and the other as user.

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // Host name 
$username="xxxxxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxxxxxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxxxxxxx"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="member"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['username']=$array['username'];
$_SESSION['password']=$array['password'];
$_SESSION['usertype']=$array['usertype'];

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

$_SESSION['username']=$_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST['password'];

if ($array['usertype']=="user")
{ header ("location: userpage.php"); }
     else if ($array['usertype']=="admin");
{ header ("location: adminpage.php"); }
   } else {
  echo "Wrong user or password";
  }
?>
```

The above is the latest code I have used. Each time I log in it seems to skip the 1st header, and go straight to the second one. I've even printed out the session after I have logged in and it does take the usertype from the table.

Don't have any more clues on how to fix this.

Comment: Note: It is not recommended to store a password in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Please , stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are not even maintained anymore. From now on you should avoid that book/tutorial, which taught you it.

Comment: @tereško Perhaps you should also suggest an alternative... The PHP tag category is brimming with inexperienced programmers who may not be aware of PDO & MySQLi.

Comment: also , it is not recommended to store un'hashed passwords in database.

Comment: You might want to look into formatting your code to help spot these little mistakes more easily, by following some coding standards. Here's an example of some easy to read code: http://codepad.org/ofwRWODj

Comment: 1st thanks for the comments. I know about the storing password thing, thats been fixed. 2nd, I do hash the passwords. Because i hardcoded these in, the login wouldnt work as the passwords werent hashed. I had to remove it to get this to work. Now that i have, I will be deleted them and hashing them

Comment: Also teresko, its the College I went to that taught me it..we've complained about the stuff they taught us being rather out of date..hell, we were using cookies not sessions when creating websites there.. Thanks for the links, i'll give them a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 errors

1. use uses double `}` after the `header ("location: adminpage.php");`
2. Semicolon `;` after `else if ($array['usertype']=="admin")`

Solution

```
if ($count == 1) {

    $_SESSION ['username'] = $_POST ['username'];
    $_SESSION ['password'] = $_POST ['password'];

    if ($array ['usertype'] == "user") {
        header ( "location: userpage.php" );
    } else if ($array ['usertype'] == "admin") {
        header ( "location: adminpage.php" );
    } else {
        echo "Wrong user or password";
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice .. but you gave someone else the credit ... its ok .. glad i could help @Greig Colliar

Comment: Yeah its just that he posted his 1st and ended up using that and it worked. I cant like both which sucks =/

Comment: funny enough .. i did not see his post before adding my .. i guess its because i opened to may windows ... Thanks anyway ... i really appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if its what's causing your problem, but you have a stray semicolon on the end of here here that needs removing:

```
else if ($array['usertype']=="admin");
```

Comment: omg it worked! How embarrassing..its always the semicolon lol.